# get ID of Create Records element in Flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, salesforce-id, visual-flows, create-records

I have a Create Records element in flow. I need the ID of the record created in this element, but I can't see anything like 'Store Id'.

Is it possible?

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A7qGkSAJ

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flows have an advanced section that allow to store data in variables.

[image]

**What type of data should the variable store?**

***Field values from a record, such as an opportunity. When this data type is selected, you create a record variable.***

and [other types of data](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/flow-builder/flow-builder-create-variable)

this can be found in the documentation and [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/flow-builder/flow-builder-create-variable)

A picklist value.
Multi-Select Picklist   Picklist values, separated by semicolons.
Apex-Defined    Field values from an Apex class. When this data type is selected, you create an Apex-defined variable.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, a record is only created after the flow ends, or after a pause element. However, no pause alement is available in screenflows. As long as the record is not created yet, no ID exstst yet either.

So if you dont have a screen flow, put a pause element right after the cretae records element: https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2020/09/08/how-to-resume-a-flow-after-x-minutes/ AFter that, you can get the created record by using filters samart.

If you have a screenflow, you cant do it like that. You might need to use two flows.

The "dirty"path:
First one that creates the new record. Then another flow that picks up the created record (You can use a flow that starts when a new record is created and have some identifier that tells SF it is that particular record, like created in the last 2 seconds by user x of type y with checkbox Z=True or something)

The clean path: use a subflow (butI'm experimenting with that myself right now, so cant help you further with that yet).